# Dirichlet series of Bernoulli polynomials

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

I am interested in the Dirichlet series
$$
\mathcal{B}(k,s) = \sum_{m\geq 1} \frac{B_k(m)}{m^s}
$$
where $B_k(x)$ is the $k$th Bernoulli polynomial and $\Re(s) > k + 1$. This converges for all $k$ and $\Re(s) > k + 1$ because the definition
$$
B_k(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^k \binom{k}{i}B_ix^{k-i}
$$
implies
$$
\mathcal{B}(k,s) = \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}B_i\zeta(i + s - k).
$$
Obviously
$$
\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{B_k(m)}{m^s} = B_k
$$
but are there any other notable properties? In particular, does it have a closed form or interesting bounds? Given the ubiquity of Bernoulli polynomials, I figured the properties of this function would be at least somewhat known, but I have yet to find a single reference on the matter.

Comment: For a polynomial $\sum_{n\ge 1} P(n) n^{-s}$ is a finite sum of $\zeta(s-k)$, I don't see what to expect more.

Comment: Dirichlet series are mainly used to study multiplicative objects, but Bernoulli polynomials appear more of an additive object.