# Approximation of Dirichlet Series over Bernoulli Polynomials

Tags: number-theory, approximation, dirichlet-series, bernoulli-polynomials

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136740/dirichlet-series-of-bernoulli-polynomials) post, the questioner asked about the behavior of a Dirichlet series over Bernoulli polynomials:

$$
\mathcal{B}(k,s) = \sum_{m\geq 1} \frac{B_k(m)}{m^s}.
$$

They show that this sum is equal to

$$
\mathcal{B}(k,s) =\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}B_i\zeta(i + s - k).
$$

which is relatively clean. However, I am curious about the concrete behavior of this latter sum. Is there a good way to approximate $\mathcal{B}(k,s)$, in the limit of large $k$? In particular, what is $\mathcal{B}(k,s)$ asymptotic to in the limit $k \rightarrow \infty$?